# Hiding specific options in select

Tags: javascript, html-select

Is it possible in JS/AJAX (**without** the use of JS frameworks like JQuery!) to hide specific < option > fields? Display:hide or Visibilty:none don't work on < option > tags...

I don't want to remove them, I just want to hide them. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Only crossbrowser working solution is to keep option list in array and each time you need to show the hidden options , just fetch it from this list.

( Use selectbox native function for adding / removing options )

I know it is not what you want exactly, but it is only working solution 
( or you can make your own combo based of divs )

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that would be the case.

Comment: I have 3 selects that are all dependent on each other, just hiding the options you don't want is easier than writing JS code to create dynamic select statements in this case. It's rather complex.